# Limit of the hypergeometric function with x tends infinity

Tags: limits, hypergeometric-function

I do not know a lot about the hypergeometric function and this is causing me problems (so if you have any references that explain them good, please let me know).

I need to compute:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left({}_{2}F_{1}\left(1,m-\frac{1}{\xi}+1;m+2;\frac{x\xi}{\mu\xi-\sigma}\right)\right)$

The ides is to get a result that can converge if $xi<1/m$. The variable $\xi, m, \sigma, \mu$ are just real numbers.

If this is complicated, I would just appreciate how I can try to solve it using m=1 and then, I will generalize it.

Thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Like all power series, ${}_2F_1$ is continuous within its radius of convergence, which is $1$.  Now as $x \to \infty$, what happens to $\frac{x\xi}{\mu\xi-\sigma}$?  If it gets $> 1$, then you are going outside the radius of convergence.  So (if you want it to exist at all), you will have to talk about an "analytic continuation" of the ${}_2F_1$.

Example, $m=1,\xi=1,\mu=1,\sigma=0$, this is
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} {}_2F_1(1,1;3;x)
$$
Here is the graph of ${}_2F_1(1,1;3;x)$

[image: graph]

There is a singularity at $x=1$.  For $x<1$ we may evaluate it as
$$
{}_2F_1(1,1;3;x) = \frac{2(1-x)\ln(1-x)+2x}{x^2}
$$
so it may be sensible to use the same formula when $x>1$.  Note that it becomes complex (non-real) for $x > 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. In case of analytical solution, I tried to use this formula https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/02/07/0005/ to transform my function into a combination of two hypergeometric functions and then use the scomposition into series. However, I cannot find a proper result. May I ask you if my approach is correct? How did you find the equation in your answer?